# set erase behaves weird

Tags: c++, stl, set

I just wrote some basic code that pushes in a few values, deletes a value by using an iterator that points to it(erase). The set does not contain that value, however the iterator still points to the deleted value.

Isn't this counter-intuitive? Why does this happen?

```
// erasing from set
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main ()
{
  std::set<int> myset;
  std::set<int>::iterator it;

  // insert some values:
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) myset.insert(i*10);  // 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90

  it = myset.begin();
  ++it;                                         // "it" points now to 20

  myset.erase (it);
  std::cout << *it << std::endl;                // still prints 20

  std::cout << "myset contains:";
  for (it=myset.begin(); it!=myset.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an invalid set iterator. The standard prescribes no rules for what happens when you dereference an invalid set iterator, so the [behavior is undefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  It is allowed to return 20.  It is allowed to do [anything else](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nasal%20demons), for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

> The set does not contain that value, however the iterator still points to the deleted value.

No, it doesn't. Not really.

> Isn't this counter-intuitive? Why does this happen?

Because the memory underneath that iterator still happens to contain the bits that make up the value `20`. That doesn't mean it's valid memory, or that those bits will always have that value.

**It's just a ghost.**

Answer (score 1):

You erased it from the set, but the iterator is still pointing to the memory that it was pointing to before you erased it.  Unless the erase did something to invalidate that memory (e.g. re-organize the entire set and write over it), the memory and its contents still exist.

**HOWEVER** it is "dead".  You should not reference it.  This is a real problem...you can't iterate over a set, calling "erase" on iterators, and expect the contents of the iterate to still be valid.  As far as I know, you can't cache iterators and expect to reference them if you are erasing the contents of the set using them.

This is also true when iterating over a list<.>.  It is tempting to iterate over a list and use the iterator to erase(.) certain elements.  But the erase(.) call breaks the linkage, so your iterator is no longer valid.

This is also true when you iterate over a vector<.>.  But it is more obvious there.  If I am at element N and call erase on it, the size of the underlying contiguous elements just got smaller by 1.

In general, it is probably a good idea to avoid operations that can effect the allocation of the underlying container (insert, erase, push_xxx, etc.) while using an iterator that will be subsequently referenced (e.g. loop, dereference after operation, etc.).